# How can I pass this array to a javascript function in an html.erb file, without erb evaluating the Date.UTC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts, erb

I'm trying to configure the HighStock Stockchart to use a two dimensional array of datetime, and value. This method is only mentioned in the Highcharts doco, not the highstock's.

I have a method in my view helper file:

```
  def byusers_chart_series(name, byusers)
          data = []
          codes_by_user = byusers.where(:hpmuser => "#{name}").group("date(hpmcreated)").select("date(hpmcreated) as dater, count(globalcode) as codes")
          codes_by_user.each do |record|
            #x = [Date.UTC("#{record.dater.year.inspect.to_i}", "#{record.dater.day.inspect.to_i}", "#{record.dater.month.inspect.to_i}"), "#{record.codes.inspect.to_i}"]
            x = [Date.UTC("#{record.dater.year.inspect.to_i}", "#{record.dater.day.inspect.to_i}", "#{record.dater.month.inspect.to_i}"), "#{record.codes.inspect.to_i}"]
            data << Array(x)
          end

          data
  end
```

This is the array that is returned, exactly as i want it to appear in the javascript:

```
[[Date.UTC(2012, 1, 2), 1],
[Date.UTC(2012, 2, 2), 5],
[Date.UTC(2012, 3, 2), 15],
[Date.UTC(2012, 6, 2), 8],
[Date.UTC(2012, 7, 2), 3],
[Date.UTC(2012, 8, 2), 73],
[Date.UTC(2012, 9, 2), 77]]
```

And this is the code from the html.ERB file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

    $(function() {
        new Highcharts.StockChart({

            chart : {
                renderTo: 'weeks52dynamic',
                borderColor: '#EBBA95',
                borderWidth: 3
            },

            legend : {
                align : "left",
                enabled : true,
                layout : "vertical",
                verticalAlign : "top"
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 0
            },

            title : {
                text : 'title'
            },

            scrollbar: {
                barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
                barBorderRadius: 7,
                barBorderWidth: 0,
                buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
                buttonBorderWidth: 0,
                buttonBorderRadius: 7,
                trackBackgroundColor: 'none',
                trackBorderWidth: 1,
                trackBorderRadius: 8,
                trackBorderColor: '#CCC'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Date"
                },

                type: "datetime",
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
         }

            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: "Number of Codes"
                }


            },
            series: [
            <% { "New Codes" => Newcode.codesperday }.each do |name, newcodes| %>
            {
                name: "<%= name %>",
                 pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
                 pointStart: <%= 350.weeks.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
                data: <%= newcodes_chart_series(newcodes, 350.weeks.ago) %>,
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius: 3
                }
            },
            <% end %>
            <% { "User" => Newcode.byuser }.each do |name, byusers| %>
            {
                name: "<%= name %>",
                data: <%= byusers_chart_series(name, byusers) %>,
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius: 3
                }
            }
            <% end %>
            ]

        });

    });


</script>
```

The error I get in my browser, I think the ERB template is trying to evaluate the Date.UTC function, rather than passing it to JavaScript for it to do. My problem is whenever I put any sort of quotes around the Data.UTC in the array or arrays, the quotes appear in the final array of arrays sent to javascript.

How can I pass that exact array of arrays without having ruby evaluate it?

Comment: One note: when you have this code: `"#{record.dater.year.inspect.to_i}"` what you are doing is saying _"Ruby, give me a number (the year); now turn it into a string (inspect); now turn that string back into a number (to_i); now turn that number back into a string._ (String interpolation `#{...}` always calls `to_s` on the result of the expression before putting it into the string.) Thus, for integers, it's just as good to use the straightforward code `"#{record.dater.year}"`.

Comment: ok, I'm adding both those simplifying techniques you told me to my code, I'm guilty of using .each and building a new array several places.

Comment: I hava a method unique_users, which gives me all the users in the DB. took it from 5 lines down to 2 using .map, ruby is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make your method simpler while we're fixing it. If you ever find yourself with code like this:

```
foo = []
bar.each{ … foo << jim }
```

…then instead you should be using this:

```
foo = bar.map{ … jim }
```

You have `Date.UTC` in your *Ruby* code, which requires Ruby to run this code while building the array. Instead of creating an array of arrays, we'll use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to convert your `codes_by_user` into an array of *strings* that are the JS code that you want:

```ruby
def byusers_chart_series(name, byusers)
  codes_by_user = byusers.where(:hpmuser => "#{name}").group("date(hpmcreated)").select("date(hpmcreated) as dater, count(globalcode) as codes")
  codes_by_user.map do |record|
    parts = %w[year month day].map{ |s| record.dater.send(s) }
    "[Date.UTC(#{parts.join(',')}),#{record.codes}]"
  end
end
```

And then in your view:

```erb
data: [ <%= byusers_chart_series(name, byusers).join(", ") %> ],
```

This will produce output like the following in your HTML:

```js
data: [ [Date.UTC(2011,10,7),42], [Date.UTC(2012,4,3),17] ],
```

Comment: Now, what if I wanted to subtract 1 from each month to account for the zero based months in javascript?

Comment: @opensourcechris You could either drop the little DRY map that I put in there, or add `parts[1]-=1` before constructing the string.